# Add querystring to all anchor links in HTML body

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

In C# given a string which contains HTML what is the best way to automatically add the query string data `test=1` to the end of every hyperlink?  It should only modify the url inside the `href` attribute for anchor links (eg not do it for image urls etc).

An example would be:

**Input**

```
<a href="http://www.test.com">Visit http://www.test.com</a> today
and see what <a href="http://www.test.com?p=1">deals</a> we have.
```

**Output**

```
<a href="http://www.test.com?test=1">Visit http://www.test.com</a> today
and see what <a href="http://www.test.com?p=1&test=1">deals</a> we have.
```

This seems to be a bit tricky and am not sure where the best place to start on this would be.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to do this client side or server side?

Answer (score 5):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) is a very fine library for parsing HTML.

Sample for get all text in html:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("Yor Path(local,web)"); 
    var result=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()");//return HtmlCollectionNode
    foreach(var node in result)
    {
        string AchivedText=node.InnerText;//Your desire text
    }
```

Comment: The HTML Agility pack has saved my bacon many times in the past few years.

Comment: You could try to write your own regular expressions to find all matches but it would be easier to just use the HTML Agility Pack for sure.

Comment: Will this work OK if the HTML is not well formed? (Missing html/body tags etc).

Comment: Yes, This library analyze a html document in tree structure even this document not be a complete html, and you can access to nodes of this tree with XPath.